# Ubuntu restricting download speed to 15kbps

Tags: 3g, broadband, download-speed

I used a 3G broadband modem. I usually would be able to get a download speed of 40 - 60 kbps when i still used windows. but it seems ubuntu has a way of restricting downloads to 15kbps. this happens for streaming sites ( youtube), synaptics/apt-get.
The only way for me to avi.

Modem model: Huawei EC226, CDMA2000 EV-DO REV.A, USB MODEM, FCC ID: QISEC226

Computer model: HP dv5 and HP dv4

Comment: Please tell us the make and model of modem you have.

Comment: HI, funny i have the same problem, usb 3g modems are way slower in ubuntu then in windows, i cant find out why. 

I tryed 3 types of modems and everytime ubuntu was slower then xp or windows 7. But i havent changed any thing, i just plug it in and say connect that it. Does anybody has a clue or a hint?  I relatively new to linux so a helping hand would be great! thanks from vienna alex

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Linux (Ubuntu in your case) does not limit the speed. In all cases i have known it boosts the speed to the maximum on the connection to the modem. you must have a router limit, modem limit or maybe you configure something on Ubuntu that changed that (For example trying to see a youtube video while downloading with transmission)

I repeat in all cases i have known since several years ago, all the PCs i have installed with Ubuntu have reported having better internet speed than any windows version. And that is about 1000 PCs, maybe more.

Comment: Are you saying you've tried ***every*** model/firmware of modems and know they all work as well if not better as they do in Windows? If you haven't, while your enthusiasm is commendable, it doesn't actually help here.

Comment: Am saying i have tried 17 types of adsl modems and 3 types of cable modems. In ALL of those cases in Linux the speed has always been greater than on windows. I do not know in your case but if the speed on Linux is lower then there most be some very weird problem. If you can provide the model AND the way you are connecting to it (Ethernet, Wireless, USB..) then that can help with the solution.

Comment: I believe it should be that way. But I and my friend (the only guys using ubuntu in my school) complain of the same problem. We use the same service provider and they use Huwaei 3g modems and we connect it by USB. When using apt-get or wget it's speed just doesn't reach what the provider offers. Only torrent downloaders, browsers and axel use the full speed. We both have had this problem since 10.04 and have been thinking maybe it's just ubuntu. I use a hp dv6 and he uses hp dv5. Thanks anyway

Comment: AAA OK. You got me there. I have only tried 5 3G models. 2 are huwaei (But if i learned something, huwaei does not care about quality but more in quantity) Can you give me the correct model. Maybe i can make a small tutorial that installs it. But remember that many 3G devices are not consistent with the speed. Where i live (Venezuela) they stay up with good speeds for seconds then drop like flies, then come up, down, up, down... BTW the hp dv6 and dv5 are good laptops. My GF has the dv6. So give me the model of the 3g modem so i can provide more help.

Comment: i think i should just write everything that was written at the back of the modem Model: EC226, CDMA2000 EV-DO REV.A, USB MODEM, FCC ID: QISEC226. That should do

Comment: In this list it is mention the EC226 as working but ONLY with wdial for the moment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G

Afterwards there are this tutorials that might help. I show add that this was the way i installed some of the modems i used. Some work straight out of the box, others needed a conf with wdial made first. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090119
http://blog.nodolibre.org/2009/05/31/modem-usb-ev-do-ccu-550-y-ec226-de-movistar-en-ubuntu-gnulinux (Spanish)
http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/111930 (Spanish) use chrome to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP reserves some bandwidht for QoS or something like that. Vista and 7 also seem to do that for similar and other purposes. Ubuntu does not do that. As mentioned by others, it seems to be faster than Windows. I recently found that ClamAV (that I use to scan Windows viruses on USB drives) sometimes works in the background and hogs bandwidth. You can install Firestarter (the firewall) and see which application is consuming the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I have that modem, but I currently use a differnet one. So I tried testing your setup and checked the speeds on both XP and 10.04LTS. My results came out pretty much the same, but a bit faster on Ubuntu since it doesn't reserve any speeds for itself. My solution for you is you should either try the version 10.04 if you aren't currently on it, or maybe you should try finding a spot with better reception or use a 3G enabled mobile phone.