# Why does my internet speed roughly *double* when switching from Ubuntu to Win XP?

Tags: networking

From the *same* Ethernet-socket from the *same* machine (IBM Thinkpad X41) I get

- > **40 Mbps** from **Win XP**
- ~ **18 Mbps** from **Ubuntu**

Apart from the fact that I'm officially paying for 50 Mbps and that for most intents and purposes anything above 10 Mbps is "good enough" for me, *why* does my internet speed roughly *double* if I boot **Win XP**?

Note: I'm *not* using <strike>wifi</strike> in this setup.

Could it be a driver / firmware issue? If so, how to check?

1. My router's got the latest firmware.
2. My modem's brand new (mfg a year ago in a Chinese sweatshop for Cisco) and from what I can tell the firmware's up-to-scratch here, too.
3. In Win XP, the latest updates are installed from Micro$oft and from the Lenovo "ThinkVantage" System Update tool.
4. Ubuntu Software Center has all the latest (LTS) updates installed.
5. I also connected it to the modem directly: internet on Ubuntu was as slow (or even slower) than when connected through the router.
6. Currently, there are no other devices connected to the router and currently online (i.e., the bandwidth is currently *not* being shared; and no, this router does *not* support <strike>wifi</strike>).

Which drivers and/or settings could I possible (and sensibly and safely) tweak within Ubuntu?

---

For older Q&A's see, for instance:

- [Internet slow on Ubuntu but not windows using a RTL8111](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94770/internet-slow-on-ubuntu-but-not-windows?rq=1)
- [Ubuntu restricting download speed to 15kbps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18293/ubuntu-restricting-download-speed-to-15kbps?rq=1)
- [Why is my download speed slow on Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103432/why-is-my-download-speed-slow-on-ubuntu-11-10)
- [Ubuntu 11.10 network speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66989/ubuntu-11-10-network-speed)
- [Slow internet browsing in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21307/slow-internet-browsing-in-ubuntu)

Note that I didn't yet test the suggestions on [How to check Internet Speed via Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal) but instead relied (for now) on the (seemingly quite reliable) [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/).

---

**Edit**

Don't take the above values as carved in stone. I do not claim to have performed robust, standardized or extensive benchmark testing. There is significant measurement error involved, which (to my knowledge) cannot be avoided entirely. I shall update my findings, if I happen to discover or test something new. In particular, I shall keep an eye out for the **top speed** reached surfing with Ubuntu (relative to > 40 Mbps with Win XP) on *this* machine/network.

Comment: How are you testing the speed?

Comment: @Mitch **speedtest.net**

Comment: try speedof.me, it could be your flash player in browser

Comment: @10robinho Tried speedof.me, no flash, just html5: but it still didn't speed up my internet on Ubuntu... never mind the accuracy of the measurement: my internet *is* quite noticable faster on windoze... arrg...

Comment: hm... there are really many possible causes. I would go with elimination. First, I would check if problem is in network card drivers - maybe you can try with wireless and check speed?

Comment: @Marky This comment has nothing to do with the question! The OP is not using wireless, you are not on Ubuntu, so what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Marky none of your comments help the OP, so why comment?

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between `Mbps` and `MBps`? `1 MBps = 8 Mbps`

Comment: @Flimm as far as I know, internet speed is commonly measured with Mbits rather than Mega- or Mebibytes... speedtest.net quotes in Mbps and/or Mbit/s...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: just checking. Sometimes I see users confused about why they haven't reached the high speeds advertised by the ISP because they don't realise the difference between Mbps and MBps. It looks like you do.

Answer (score 8):

It could be the duplex of your ethernet port conflicting with your switch/router.  You can check this by using "ethtool".

If "eth0" is the ethernet port you're using, run:

```
sudo /sbin/ethtool eth0
```

...and look for a line that says "Duplex:".  Most modern home switches/routers will support "Full" duplex and that should be the most optimal setting.  The other possible would be "Half".

Regardless of the value, you can change to the other by running:

```
sudo /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 full
```

which sets the port to full duplex.  To force half duplex, run:

```
sudo /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 half
```

Confirm by running the first ethtool command, then re-run your speed tests.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible your only getting half duplex under Ubuntu. What network card and module are you using?

Also make sure your DNS settings are the same as in Windows, could be name resolution taking longer and making it appear slower.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an *experienced user* but as you can see in the image.:

[image: speedtest image]

I've got the same connection.

That happened to me while using an old Ubuntu version, and the problem was that my computer wireless USB adapter was 802.11g. When I change it to 802.11n the problem was solved (its possible you only need to adapt the drivers).

I know that with your computer knowledge this could be a *stupid answer*, but consider my intereset on helping.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How does this answer the question? That is, what is it, specifically, that you're recommending the original poster *do* to help this problem? That's not totally clear in this answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ubuntu isn't to blame, there can be something with your router.  The OS doesn't slow down internet connection. Check firewall settings, IP settings, DNS,  and see if you have the latest NIC drivers.

Also try turning off internet sharing by unchecking Available to all users.  I just tried it, ans it made a difference.  To do so see below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

With the option **Unchecked**

[image]

With the option **Checked**

[image]

> Download speed has virtually nothing to do with a computer's
> processing power. Assuming your computer is able to run whatever
> operating system you're running and that it has a 10/100 ethernet
> port, your download speeds won't be affected any further by anything
> on that machine. Download speeds are affected mostly by the server
> you're connecting to and however busy the network traffic between you
> and that server is, and obviously the speed of your connection you're
> paying your internet service provider for.<sup>1</sup>
>
> OS is nothing to deal with your download speed. This concerns on your
> internet connection or ISP, your device that you're using in your PC
> for internet access (example: LAN and Modem, Network Setup, Router
> (the setup), Wireless Devices, and many more), and the bandwidth speed
> that your ISP gave you to access different location using your
> internet (means that different Server Speed or Location-Range will
> affect your DL Speed). But, some softwares like Web Browser, Download
> Manager, and other programs that affects your access in the internet
> have a effect too, but the effect is less than what you expected.<sup>1</sup>

> **What Affects Speed?** Every web page you view or file downloaded from the Internet is handled by dozens of computers before it appears
> on your screen. And the speed you receive from the Internet is
> determined by the slowest “link” in the data chain leading to your
> computer. Below, are some factors that can affect the speed of your
> Broadband connection.
>
> **The Host Server** The most common cause of slow speed on the Internet is the host server. This server may be miss-configured or
> underpowered for the number of people using it at the same time. A
> slow server can affect anything you do on the Internet.
>
> **Ad-aware or Spy-ware** If your computer is infected with "ad-aware" or "spy-ware" you will likely see reduced computer performance and a
> constant stream of pop-up ads. This will likely cause everything on
> your computer to work slower.
>
> **Web Browser** A corrupted or poorly configured web browser is one of the most common bottlenecks for fast web browsing.
>
> **Your TCP/IP Configuration** Installation software provided by dial-up Internet providers and satellite companies can change the
> default TCP/IP settings on your computer in an attempt to provide
> better performance. These changes usually cause poorer performance
> with high-speed Internet services and should be uninstalled.

**Having a good knowledge of DNS and how to change your settings, can speed up your connection.**

> **Your Computer Hardware** The speed of the processor, hard drive, network card, graphics accelerator, even the amount of RAM, all impact
> the speed your computer can process Internet data.
>
> **Your Operating System** With extensive use, any computer operating system can become corrupted, inefficient or miss-configured, which
> will affect the speed.  **(User Responsibility)**
>
> **Your Home Networking Device** A home networking device, or router, routes traffic between your cable modem and your computer(s). Routers
> that don't use 100baseT Ethernet standards or outdated software could
> slow your connection.
>
> **Your Modem's Signal** If the Modem signal delivered to your cable/dsl modem is too strong, too weak or too noisy, it can cause
> your Modem to slow down or stop working entirely. Any changes to
> your line, inside or outside, could also slow your modem signal.
>
> **Type of Connection** The most important determining factor for Internet speed is the type of Internet connection you have. You can
> purchase Internet service at different levels of speeds, depending
> upon what the provider offers. Normally speeds range from 1.5
> megabytes per second to 6 megabytes per second, which are the download
> and upload times that it takes the Internet to send and receive
> information.
>
> **Time of Day** For many types of Internet, such as those that are connected through phone lines or coaxial cables, the time of day can
> be a factor. Modem-based Internet and DSL are both shared network
> systems---meaning that if many people within your neighborhood are
> using the Internet, it can slow down your Internet connection due to
> clogged bandwidth, which is responsible for data transmission.
>
> **Computer Memory** Even if you purchase a higher speed of Internet service, you can only utilize these higher speeds if your computer has
> the capabilities. One major speed factor within the computer is the
> amount of memory---or RAM---that it has. RAM is responsible for
> temporarily storing a computer's instructions. Lack of RAM means that
> a computer must store instructions on the hard drive, which takes
> longer to execute.
>
> **Processor Speed** The processor speed---or the speed at which your computer executes and transfers instructions---is the other aspect
> that defines the speed of the computer, as well as its Internet
> connection. If you have a high Internet speed, but don't have a high
> enough processor speed, the computer won't be able to execute
> instructions fast, resulting in a slower speed of Internet
> interaction.
>
> **Virus** Another possible threat that can slow down Internet speed is a virus. If you don't have a good virus protector installed, then
> viruses can infect your computer, which can cause a tremendous
> decrease in the speed at which all operations are performed, including
> the Internet connection.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Gendou](http://gendou.com/t/23028)</sup>
<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Sources:[MTC](http://www.mtcbroadband.net/faq.php?p=speed) [ehow](http://www.ehow.com/about_6303198_affects-speed-internet_.html)</sup>

Comment: Curious to learn whether this tick-box could "steal" the internet-connection from all users connected via that router... is that so? Regarding my speed: no change (within the very large margin of error)...

Comment: @Mitch "Also try turning off internet sharing by unchecking Available to all users. I just tried it, ans it **made a difference**." Could you put a number to it?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty that option does not affect the router.

Comment: @vasa1 Added images to show the difference.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure I can agree to *"the OS is not to blame"*: what about drivers? Whether you count them as belonging to an OS or not, that might be the bottle-neck, no? I also connected my laptop to the modem directly (thus ruling out router-interference): still no-where near speed "equality".

Comment: Try booting a LiveCD/LiveUSB of a different version of Ubuntu, or maybe a different distro (Fedora, etc). There may be changes to the driver at some point.

Comment: My comment above gets deleted while the answer of "Available to all users" which is highly likely is not the cause of the slow speed is voted up? Really mods? C'mon guys! I'm not a networking expert but this supposed answer above doesn't even hold anything to explain the cause of the halved speed on Ubuntu as compared to XP.

Comment: The "Available to all users" just allows non-root enabled users to turn it on/off.

Comment: @dan_linder If you're referring to standard users, they can't adjust that value.  If they try, it will present them to enter the Administrator's password.

Comment: @Mitch For the sake of clarity etc, may I kindly ask you to open a new answer with your edit? I fail to see the connection between the "checkbox" and the more general info quoted below... thanks for your input(s) !

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty This has nothing to do with the "checkbox".  Its intended to clarify the different things that affect internet connectivity, since `I don't personally` think that the OS has much to do with internet speed.  As far as adding another answer, I'd rather keep one answer, if its OK.  Thanks

Comment: as @dan_linder stated, the checkbox has no bearing on the speed of the connection at all. It can only be set by an admin, but once set any user is then allowed to turn the connection on and off through network manager. without the admin having set the option ordinary users are unable to use network manager to alter the connectivity of that connection.

Comment: @DanielLlewellyn That option made a difference in my specific situation, as I stated.  the issue at hand: Does an OS affect the speed of the connection?  `I don't personally think so`.